# How to identify the indices of certain characters in this array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

For my game, I read in text file in order to set up my map. The text file is a series of characters separated by commas, with each character representing a tile in the game. For example, a section of my map file may look like this:

> fr,g,g,
>
> g,fy,w,
>
> g,g,w,

In this, "fr" stands for flower red, "g" stands for grass, "w" stands for water, etc. Now the problem is that the map is much bigger than the section of the map that is displayed. For example, the map file may be the following:

> g,g,g,w,g,g,fr
>
> g,fy,w,w,g,g,g
>
> g,g,w,g,g,fr,g
>
> g,g,fy,g,g,w,g

But I would only display a 3x3 section of these tiles at a time, so for example I can display the 3x3 section of the above map file at the top right of the map, which would be the tiles:

> g,g,g,w,**g,g,fr**
>
> g,fy,w,w,**g,g,g**
>
> g,g,w,g,**g,fr,g**
>
> g,g,fy,g,g,w,g

But since I read this file into a 1 dimensional array (there are no 2D arrays in Objective-C), my problem is that I cannot figure out how to identify the indices of the section I want to display.

So this map will be internally represented as (bolded characters are characters that will be displayed):

> g,g,g,w,**gz,g,fr**,g,fy,w,w,**g,g,g**,g,g,w,g,**g,fr,g**,g,g,fy,g,g,w,g

I identify the start character with a "z", so the above map may appear like this if I want to display the top right section:

> g,g,g,w,**gz,g,fr**
>
> g,fy,w,w,**g,g,g**
>
> g,g,w,g,**g,fr,g**
>
> g,g,fy,g,g,w,g

My question is **how can I identify the indices of the characters that make up the section I want to display?**

**EDIT:**
I fixed my code according to what @Ted's answer, but the results are strange. This is the algorithm that I drew up:

```
NSMutableArray *nodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int tilesAcross = DEVICE_WIDTH/TILE_WIDTH;
int tilesUp = DEVICE_HEIGHT/TILE_HEIGHT;

int startX = self.renderer.indexOfStartNode / BIOME_WIDTH;
int startY = self.renderer.indexOfStartNode % BIOME_WIDTH;

for(int index = 0; index < self.entireMap.count; index++) {

    int currentX = index / BIOME_WIDTH;
    int currentY = index % BIOME_WIDTH;

    if((currentX > startX && currentX <= (startX + tilesAcross)) && (currentY > startY && currentY <= (startY + tilesUp))) {

        [nodes addObject:[self.entireMap objectAtIndex:index]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a complete answer but isn't the 1D -> 2D transition pretty trivial? A 2D array is still stored in memory... which is linear (so can be thought of as a 1D array). So say you want element `(i,j)` well then in a 1D array this would have index `i*LENGTH_OF_ROW + j`. Once you can handle that, you can do all of your calculations as if it were a 2D grid. But I-know-nothing-about-Objective-C so YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix with width `w` stored row-by-row in a linear array, you can convert back and forth between a linear index `i` and coordinates `row`, `column` using the formulas:

```
i = row * w + column
row = i / w
column = i % w
```

This is valid for zero-based indexing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This is nearly what I want. Just one thing: if I have an object with index `i`, how can I convert its index to coordinates?

Comment: @qegal - That's what the last two lines do. You just need to know the index itself and the width of the underlying matrix.

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry for missing that. Thanks you so much!

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the edit? I drew up some code according to your answer but the code's not working. Thanks!

Comment: @qegal - I think you have to reverse the calculations for `currentX` and `currentY`. The x coordinate is usually the column (horizontal position index) and the y coordinate is the row (vertical position index).

Comment: The code still isn't working (sorry to keep nagging you, I'm just been working at this problem for a while and am a little desperate at this point)

Comment: @qegal - Can you provide a little more detail about what way it is not working?

Comment: Sure. Before, my map file contained only the tiles that would be displayed on the screen, so if I displayed only 3 rows and 3 columns of tiles on the screen, the map file would only contain 9 tiles. Now, the map file contains many more tiles than I display on the screen (this was necessary to move my project along), and I need to find a way to identify which tiles to display on the screen. If this were working properly, it would look like this: <http://imgur.com/77VEmtW.png>. But it really looks like this: <http://i.imgur.com/t9xzOyt.png>

Comment: @qegal - I'm not sure what all your variables mean, but I'm guessing that your `if` condition is off a bit. Shouldn't it be `(currentX >= startX && currentX < (startX + tilesAcross)) && (currentY >= startY && currentY < (startY + tilesUp))`? (Note the change in the comparison operators.)

Comment: I compared actual coordinates in the map file with the bounds imposed by the if condition, and verified that what I had was correct. Which variables confuse you? Perhaps I can explain them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28779/discussion-between-ted-hopp-and-qegal)

Comment: I fixed it after spending another hour on it! :) Just letting you know.

Comment: @qegal - Cool! If it was something that might help others, consider editing your question and adding an explanation of what got it to work.